# Active records: Working with a db object

Tags: php, database, object

I want to be able to select multiple rows with one query. I was wondering if you can do something like this?

```
$teamsQuery = $this->db;

foreach( $teamids as $teamid )
$teamsQuery->where('teamid', $teamid);

$teamsQuery->get('team');

$teams = $teamsQuery->result();

print_r($teams);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, an [ActiveRecord](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) wraps a single row in a database in an object and attaches business and persistence logic to it. If you want to fetch multiple rows with one query, have a look at [TableDataGateway](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html).

In the TableDateGateway you would have a method `findTeamsByIds` which you will pass the entire array of IDs and then fetch those in a `SELECT … WHERE … IN` query.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this type of function

```
 /**
 * get all data from the table
 *
 * @param string $sql - mySQL query string
 *
 * @return data as associative array
 * */
function getAll($sql) {
    $res = mysql_query($sql);

    if (!$res) {
        die(mysql_error());
    }

    // Convert to array
    $ret = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        // Add to array
        $index = count($ret);
        $ret[$index] = $row;
    }

    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: what is that while loop for? It fetches the row as an associative array and then assigns the row to  $ret[$index] but because $index is always the same number $ret will contain the last returned row only.